# How to get rid of a pop up window saying that not all sections were completely synchronized when synchronizing OneNote Notebooks

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote

I get a pop up window when I try to synchronize OneNote Notebooks in the desktop OneNote with the online OneNote. When clicking on `Files` -> `Show synchronization status` in the desktop OneNote, one of the synchronizations fails. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the notebook in the desktop OneNote that does not synchronize well. Afterwards, open it again. Synchronization should already be done by then, and you can check it by clicking on `Files` -> `Show synchronization status` in the desktop OneNote again.